# Disable click when displaying jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am new to jQuery. I am creating an asp.net MVC application.

I am displaying a dialog when user clicks on a button using the following code.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $dialog = $("#quantityDialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      title: 'Add to Cart',
    });
    $('.AddToCart').on('click', function () {
      $dialog.dialog('open');
    });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="quantityDialog" style="display:none">
...
</div>
```

**The dialog is working fine.**

1. I need to restrict the user from being able to click other elements of the page when the dialog is being displayed.
2. Also when the user clicks elsewhere (outside the dialog box) the dialog has to be closed.

How can I achieve this. Help me out.

Comment: You need an overlay element to go under the dialog. There is an option to jQueryUI Dialog to do that already see http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: You can use colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ to show dialog it will give you more functionality like iframe inline etc to open dialog

Comment: there is an option for that: `modal: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#loadPreviewDiv").click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            title: "Dialog box",
            height: 300,
            modal: true,
            open: function() {
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function() {
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        },
            buttons: { "close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } 
        });
 });
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2hyAh/1/

Comment: your solution works but when I click outside the box the dialog is not getting closed!

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/5nkcz/)**

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $dialog = $("#quantityDialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal:true,//to display an overlay
      title: 'Add to Cart',
    });

$('.AddToCart').on('click', function () {
  $dialog.dialog('open');
});



/*When clicked on overlay close the dailog*/
   $('div.ui-widget-overlay').click(function(){
       $dialog.dialog('close');
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `modal` property of dialog box to achieve the background overlay ,

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        .....
    });
```

And to close on `overlay` you can bind the `.ui-widget-overlay` in `open` of dialog box as ::

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        ......
        open: function(){
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click',function(){
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            });
        ....
        }
```

Comment: solution works but when I click outside the box the dialog is not getting closed!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution,

1. Diable click of other area

   Here you can add one dom to overlap the other area

   ```
   <div class="overlay"></div>
   ```

   And write the css for this dom

   ```
   .overlay {
       display: none;
       position: fixed;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       opacity: 0;
       z-index: 1;
   }
   ```

   When you open the popup, you can show this overlay by simply writing this.

   ```
   $('.overlay').show();
   ```

   Note : Make sure that popup z-index is greater than the overlay.
2. Close the popup on click outside of it

   ```
   $('body').click(function(e){
       if(!$(e.target).is('.AddToCart, #quantityDialog'))
       {
           // write logic to close the popup here
           $('.overlay').hide();
       }
   })
   ```